# Делегаты и производительность

Tags: c#

Делегат это ссылка на метод. То есть если мы делаем элементарную реализацию типа такой:

```
public delegate void del1(string message);
...
{
del1 objdel=new del1(ShowMessage);
}
public static void ShowMessage(string message)
{

}
```

Это просто вызов функции. Но например если мы делаем анонимный метод типа такого:

```
public delegate void del1(string message);
...
{
del1 objdel=delegate(string message){
...
};
}
```

То в этом случае, ради такой конструкции будет создаваться отдельный класс, и в нем будет создаваться метод для выполнения? И поэтому если часто использовать такие методы то это скажется негативно на производительности, так?

Comment: Ну создайте бенчмарк да проверьте.

Comment: По поводу класса для метода, поясните подробнее, что имеете ввиду?

Comment: @tym32167 компилятор при проходе по коду с анонимными функциями создаёт что то вроде временного класса для этой функции и при наличии таковых туда заносятся внешние переменные если таковые употребляются в анонимной функции , как и сказали ниже

Comment: Из того, что я помню, временный класс создается только если вы захватываете переменные внутри анонимной функции. Если же функция оперирует только своими переметрами и ничего не захватывает, то не вижу смысла создавать для неё класс.

Comment: @tym32167 не, ты не понял. Класс создается автоматически на стадии компиляции. Мы его не создаем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда ты объявляешь тип делегата, компилятор генерирует код класса-делегата (который наследуется от MulticastDelegate) - это и есть его сущность. Благодаря статической типизации компилятор может еще на этапе компиляции проверить соответствие сигнатуры метода, который ты передал в конструктор класса делегата (new Action(method), например), самому делегату.
Я не знаю как на низком уровне работают делегаты, но однозначно перед непосредственным выполнением обернутого в делегат метода существует несколько дополнительных операций: Action act; act() или act.Invoke() - одно и то же. act() компилятором преобразуется в act.Invoke() - своего рода синтаксический сахар. Так вот о накладных операциях: в стеке появится вызов Invoke -> возможно еще чего-то -> самого метода. 
В последнем абзаце я думаю ты имел ввиду это:

Вот такой код:

```
using System;

namespace tester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var act = new Action(() => Console.Write(true));
        }
    }
}
```

Скомпилируется в -

```
// tester.Program
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using tester;

internal class Program
{
    [Serializable]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

        public static Action <>9__0_0;

        internal void <Main>b__0_0()
        {
            Console.Write(true);
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //Здесь проверяется создан ли экземпляр делегата, и его создание в противном случае.   
       //Таким образом, можно говорить, что создание делегата для анонимной ф-ции выполняется один раз за работу программы (если нет захвата внешних переменных).
        Action act = <>c.<>9__0_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__0_0 = new Action(<>c.<>9.<Main>b__0_0));
    }
}
```

Стоит сказать, что разницы нет, что метод в другом классе. 
Такой код чище выходит:

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Print() => Console.Write(true);
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var act = new Action(Print);
            }

        }
```

Декомпиляция:

```
    // tester.Program
    using System;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Print()
        {
            Console.Write(true);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action act = Print;
        }
    }
```

И посмотрим на его IL:

[image]

А в этом случае при каждом вызове метода заново создается экземпляр делегата. В предыдущем, напомню, у нас каждый раз при вызове метода проверяется создавали ли мы уже экземпляр (причем поля-то были статичные). Что дороже решайте сами (я так думаю проверка легковесней). Но оптимизировать код так: экономия на спичках.
И еще один момент, зачем все-таки создается класс под анонимную ф-цию? Для захвата внешних переменных. Пример:

```
    using System;

    namespace tester
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int count = 1;
                var del = new Action(delegate () {
                    Console.WriteLine(count);
                });
            }

        }
    }
```

Сигнатура Action - безпараметричная - ф-ция. Но фактически внутри идет вывод значения count, то есть передача параметра. Для этого и создается обертка.
Видим:

```
    // tester.Program
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using tester;

    internal class Program
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
        {
            public int count;

            internal void <Main>b__0()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Создается класс-обертка, которая захватит внешние переменные метода.
            <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
           //Захват переменной. Тут даже оптимизация (count - не переменная метода, а экземпляра оболочки для захвата)
            <>c__DisplayClass0_.count = 1;
            //Создание экземпляра.
            Action del = new Action(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<Main>b__0);
        }
    }
```

Кстати, когда используется экземплярный метод для оборачивания делегатом, тогда происходит захват и самой сущности (экземпляра то есть).
Вот сигнатура конструктора Action:
 [image: Конструктор]
Первый аргумент: ссылка this для экземплярного метода или null, если метод неэкземплярный. А второй - IntPtr-ссылка на метод. Вот кусочек из первого примера:
[image]
Что можно сказать на последок... Вызов делегата - это не просто вызов ф-ции. Автоматический захват внешних переменных - классно и удобно. Раньше еще использовали анонимные ф-ции не только для передачи куда-то (например, для обработчика события), а еще в роли локальных ф-ций. Удобно это потому, что анонимные ф-ции позволяли выполнять захват внешних переменных и не приходилось писать огромную тучу аргументов для вызова. То есть:

```
    using System;

    namespace tester
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int count = 1;
                var inc = new Action(() => count += 15);
                inc();
                inc();
            }

        }
    }
```

Вместо того, чтобы сделать ф-цию void inc(int count) - т.к. это более громоздко. Но недавно в C# ввели локальные ф-ции и теперь это работает более оптимально, нежели когда это реализовывалось посредством делегатов:

```
    using System;

    namespace tester
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int count = 1;
                void printCount() => Console.WriteLine(count);
                printCount();
            }

        }
    }
```

Скомпилируется в -

```
    // tester.Program
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using tester;

    internal class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
        [CompilerGenerated]
        private struct <>c__DisplayClass0_0
        {
            public int count;
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = default(<>c__DisplayClass0_0);
            <>c__DisplayClass0_.count = 1;
            <Main>g__printCount|0_0(ref <>c__DisplayClass0_);
        }

        [CompilerGenerated]
        internal static void <Main>g__printCount|0_0(ref <>c__DisplayClass0_0 P_0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(P_0.count);
        }
    }
```

Вот тут действительно просто вызов ф-ции + структура для захвата внешних аргументов. 
И отвечая на твой финальный вопрос: нет. Эти 2 (с использованием анонимок и оборачиванием ф-ции класса) варианта особо не уступают друг другу в производительности. Мне еще нравится юзать локальные ф-ции для оборачивания в делегаты - более стройный код получается. Интересно во что это компилится. Но проверять не буду.

Answer (score 2):

Делегат - это также специальный класс, унаследованный от [MulticastDelegate](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate?view=netcore-2.1).

Вообще, чтобы присвоить анонимный метод чему-то, надо, чтобы это что-то имело явно определённый тип:

```
using System;

namespace CSrharpApplicationTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action x = delegate () // С var не сработает.
            {
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Так происходит потому что может возникнуть неоднозначность, как в следующем случае:

```
namespace CSrharpApplicationTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public delegate void A();
        public delegate void B();

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = delegate () // Что выбрать в качестве типа x - A или B? Компилятору не ясно.
            {
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Хочется заметить, что может возникнуть вопрос такого рода: Почему в местах где нет неоднозначности такое не разрешили? Я думаю, что так поступили для большей стандартизации кода и облегчения его написания. Ибо если бы разрешили такое поведение с `var`, то при добавлении ссылки на пространство имён, содержащем делегат с похожей сигнатурой могла возникнуть неоднозначность, что означало бы дополнительное время на правку кода.

Возвращаясь к первому примеру, в нём я создаю неявно экземпляр делегата `Action` со ссылкой на метод, содержимого которого заключено в `{}`. То есть, здесь (в контексте этого примера) всё происходит ровно также как и без использования анонимных методов:

```
using System;

namespace CSrharpApplicationTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Method()
        {
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action x = Method;
        }
    }
}
```

Так что с точки производительности различий не будет. Следует понимать, что делегаты - это более безопасное средство для ссылок на методы, нежели указатели в C++, за что приходится платить производительностью в некоторой степени.

Обращаю внимание на то, что обычно указывают тип переменной явно, а не используют `var`.

Comment: Не понятно зачем вы про `var` в ответе пишете? Не все используют `var` для объявления локальных переменных. `var` — зло.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил внизу комментарий на счёт `var`. Хотя, я видел рекомендации в стиле `используйте var только там, где тип переменной очевиден`, но очевидность, на мой взгляд - субъективный и неточный критерий, поэтому, в частности, я не прибегаю к использованию `var`.